# Problem with kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, deployment, ubuntu-server

I have a problem during deployment process of my web app (a university's project) to Ubuntu Server from Macbook with my university's VPN. This is my first time deploying a software so this is a lot of new things for me.

I was trying to configure the server to work with localhost (127.0.0.1) when then i can't connect anymore to the ssh, with this error message showing up:

```
reynaldjhonson@Reynalds-MacBook-Air ~ % ssh swtp@swtp-ekg.ges.thm.de
kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
Connection reset by 10.197.245.113 port 22
```

This is my ssh -v

```
reynaldjhonson@Reynalds-MacBook-Air ~ % ssh swtp@swtp-ekg.ges.thm.de -v
OpenSSH_8.6p1, LibreSSL 2.8.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/* matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 54: Applying options for *
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug1: Connecting to swtp-ekg.ges.thm.de port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/reynaldjhonson/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/reynaldjhonson/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/reynaldjhonson/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/reynaldjhonson/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/reynaldjhonson/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/reynaldjhonson/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/reynaldjhonson/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/reynaldjhonson/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/reynaldjhonson/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/reynaldjhonson/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/reynaldjhonson/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/reynaldjhonson/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/reynaldjhonson/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/reynaldjhonson/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.6
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
Connection closed by 10.197.245.113 port 22
```

and telnet

```
telnet 10.197.245.113 22
Trying 10.197.245.113...
Connected to swtp-ekg.ges.thm.de.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

I have read a lot of solutions given on Internet to change some conf file in the server, but i can't even access the server from my Macbook.

I really appreciate any help or tips!
Thanks!

Comment: Hi did you find the solution to this?

Comment: Hi, the problem is solved from the administrator's side. I was locked out from the server and need to be given new permission to access it by the administrator. So yeah.